# Get count of days for most extreme variable based on a range with possible overlapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with records which have been manually entered. In the database there are two fields (start and end dates) which have been entered. Along with entering these dates the user also puts in a priority. I need to be able to extract the range of days (inclusive of all days) as a number for the highest priority with the date range these are placed against (all in the last lot of columns).

Below is one record from the database:

```
OurID   TotalCalculatedKnownDays    Priority    KnownStartDate          KnownEndDate            CategoryCode    ExternalID  InputtedStartDate       InputtedEndDate         InputeedCalulatedDays   Month
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    5                           3           2013-11-20 18:04:00.000 2013-11-24 23:20:00.000 XX1             5678        2013-11-20 00:00:00.000 2013-11-24 00:00:00.000 5                       Nov-13
1234    5                           4           2013-11-20 18:04:00.000 2013-11-24 23:20:00.000 XX1             5678        2013-11-24 00:00:00.000 2013-11-24 00:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
1234    5                           4           2013-11-20 18:04:00.000 2013-11-24 23:20:00.000 XX1             5678        2013-11-24 00:00:00.000 2013-11-25 11:00:00.000 2                       Nov-13
1235    3                           2           2013-11-07 10:45:00.000 2013-11-09 23:45:00.000 XX2             5640        2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 2013-11-08 00:00:00.000 2                       Nov-13
1235    3                           3           2013-11-07 10:45:00.000 2013-11-09 23:45:00.000 XX2             5640        2013-11-08 00:00:00.000 2013-11-09 00:00:00.000 2                       Nov-13
1235    3                           4           2013-11-07 10:45:00.000 2013-11-09 23:45:00.000 XX2             5640        2013-11-09 00:00:00.000 2013-11-09 00:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
```

What I need is, output a corrected list like this:

```
OurID   TotalCalculatedKnownDays    Priority    KnownStartDate          KnownEndDate            CategoryCode    ExternalID  InputtedStartDate       InputtedEndDate         InputeedCalulatedDays   Month
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    5                           3           2013-11-20 18:04:00.000 2013-11-24 23:20:00.000 XX1             5678        2013-11-20 00:00:00.000 2013-11-23 00:00:00.000 4                       Nov-13
1234    5                           4           2013-11-20 18:04:00.000 2013-11-24 23:20:00.000 XX1             5678        2013-11-24 00:00:00.000 2013-11-24 00:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
1234    5                           4           2013-11-20 18:04:00.000 2013-11-24 23:20:00.000 XX1             5678        2013-11-25 00:00:00.000 2013-11-25 11:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
1235    3                           2           2013-11-07 10:45:00.000 2013-11-09 23:45:00.000 XX2             5640        2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 2013-11-07 00:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
1235    3                           3           2013-11-07 10:45:00.000 2013-11-09 23:45:00.000 XX2             5640        2013-11-08 00:00:00.000 2013-11-08 00:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
1235    3                           4           2013-11-07 10:45:00.000 2013-11-09 23:45:00.000 XX2             5640        2013-11-09 00:00:00.000 2013-11-09 00:00:00.000 1                       Nov-13
```

I have been able to get a list of unique days for each of the ID’s and it’s ok if the details are broken down by each day (although preferably not if there’s a way to do it as above), but I can’t work out how to allocate the highest priority recorded for that day against OurID. Below is what I have for this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    OurID VARCHAR(10),
    TotalCalculatedKnownDays INT,
    Priority VARCHAR(50),
    KnownStartDate datetime,
    KnownEndDate datetime,
    CategoryCode varchar(10),
    ExternalID varchar(10),
    InputtedStartDate datetime,
    InputtedEndDate datetime,
    [Days] int,
    [Month] varchar(10)
);

insert into @t
select p. OurID, DATEDIFF(DAY, i. KnownStartDate, i. KnownEndDate) + 1 AS TotalCalculatedKnownDays, p. Priority, i. KnownStartDate, i. KnownEndDate, i. CategoryCode, p. ExternalID, CONVERT(DATETIME, p. InputtedStartDate, 120) as 'InputtedStartDate', CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(p. InputtedEndDate1, DATEADD(dd, 1, p. InputtedEndDate2)), 120) as 'InputtedEndDate', DATEDIFF(DAY, p. InputtedStartDate, ISNULL(p. InputtedEndDate1, DATEADD(dd, 1, p. InputtedEndDate2))) + 1 AS 'Days', CONVERT(CHAR(3), i.KnownEndDate, 100) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), i. KnownEndDate, 12) as 'Month'
from openquery(ls1,'XXXXX') p
INNER JOIN [tbl2] i ON i. ExternalID = p. ExternalID and i.OurID = p.OurID
;

with [range](d,s) as
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN InputtedStartDate), MAX InputtedEndDate))+1,
    MIN(InputtedStartDate)
    FROM @t
),
n(d) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, (SELECT MIN(s) FROM [range]))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects) AS s(n)
    WHERE n <= (SELECT MAX(d) FROM [range])
)
select tRef.* from (
SELECT distinct t.OurID, n.d
FROM n CROSS JOIN @t AS t
WHERE n.d BETWEEN t InputtedStartDate AND t InputtedEndDate) tRef
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Do you want to correctly calculate the column `InputeedCalulatedDays`?

Comment: That is only half the problem. The other half is the dates would need to be edited. Based on the the higest priority taking precedence over the lower priority. The corrected output shows what would be best to be returned by the SQL statement.

Comment: So where does `2013-11-25 11:00:00.000` end date come from for the last record for order `1234`?

Comment: That is an example of a record that has been entered wrong. In the original table inputted start date is 24th, end date is 25th. In the fixed version even though this is wrong (as the date is after the known end date) it should show up (although it can [well, should] be joined with the record above it as it has the same priority code but I did that example quickly and din't notice that error). As you see, even though we are expecting 5 days this record should tally to 6 days due to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a solution which works based on each individual day. It's not the best solution, but it works and pulls out each day and the highest priority. Would be great if the first solution could still be found, but for now this will do.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    OurID VARCHAR(10),
    TotalCalculatedKnownDays INT,
    Priority VARCHAR(50),
    KnownStartDate datetime,
    KnownEndDate datetime,
    CategoryCode varchar(10),
    ExternalID varchar(10),
    InputtedStartDate datetime,
    InputtedEndDate datetime,
    [Days] int,
    [Month] varchar(10)
);

insert into @t
select p. OurID, DATEDIFF(DAY, i. KnownStartDate, i. KnownEndDate) + 1 AS TotalCalculatedKnownDays, p. Priority, i. KnownStartDate, i. KnownEndDate, i. CategoryCode, p. ExternalID, CONVERT(DATETIME, p. InputtedStartDate, 120) as 'InputtedStartDate', CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(p. InputtedEndDate1, DATEADD(dd, 1, p. InputtedEndDate2)), 120) as 'InputtedEndDate', DATEDIFF(DAY, p. InputtedStartDate, ISNULL(p. InputtedEndDate1, DATEADD(dd, 1, p. InputtedEndDate2))) + 1 AS 'Days', CONVERT(CHAR(3), i.KnownEndDate, 100) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), i. KnownEndDate, 12) as 'Month'
from openquery(ls1,'XXXXX') p
INNER JOIN [tbl2] i ON i. ExternalID = p. ExternalID and i.OurID = p.OurID
;

with [range](d,s) as
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN InputtedStartDate), MAX InputtedEndDate))+1,
    MIN(InputtedStartDate)
    FROM @t
),
n(d) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, (SELECT MIN(s) FROM [range]))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects) AS s(n)
    WHERE n <= (SELECT MAX(d) FROM [range])
)
select tRef.* from (
select orig.OurID, MAX(orig.TotalCalculatedKnownDays) AS 'TotalCalculatedKnownDays', MAX(orig.Priority) as 'Priority', MIN(KnownStartDate) as 'KnownStartDate', MAX(KnownEndDate) as 'KnownEndDate', MAX(orig.CategoryCode) as 'CategoryCode', MAX(orig.ExternalID) as 'ExternalID', tRef.d as 'Chargeable Date', MAX(orig.month) as 'Month' from (
SELECT distinct t.OurID, n.d
FROM n CROSS JOIN @t AS t
WHERE n.d BETWEEN t.InputtedStartDate AND t.InputtedEndDate) tRef
LEFT JOIN @t as orig ON tRef.OurID = orig.OurID AND tRef.d BETWEEN orig.InputtedStartDate AND orig.InputtedEndDate
GROUP BY orig.OurID, tRef.d
order by 1, 8;
```